# Not able to get proper dark icons with android:windowLightStatusBar

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-statusbar

I am trying to make the status bar of my app White and using android:windowLightStatusBar to get the dark status bar icons but All i am able to get is[image]

As you can see Some of the icons(like the network icons are not visible)

Here is the code I am trying this with

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorWhite</item>

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorMainBackground</item>

    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
</style>
```

What could be causing this if anyone could tell, it would be a great help...Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try running your app on a different phone or the emulator. There's no way to control the color of the status bar icons and your code regarding `windowLightStatusBar` looks fine.

Comment: Yes it seems that it was a device issue..Thanx !!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're putting `android:windowLightStatusBar` in `values-v23/styles.xml`
if you're API level is lower than 23 than declare

`<item name="colorPrimaryDark" tools:targetApi="23">@color/colorPrimary</item>
  <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>` `in v21/Style`

Comment: i have written the above code in values-v23/styles.xml file

Comment: what is your current API level.